# Adding and removing Sticky class on Javascript up and Down scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, sticky

i m new to JS and i m trying to create sticky video player like http://www.standard.co.uk/stayingin/tvfilm/jamestown-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-sky1-drama-a3531796.html. When user scrolls up or down sticky class get added to video player. I have done some work https://jsfiddle.net/oLythd3f/ . but i want to also add function which check the bottom and once i scroll down i want sticky class to be added.

not sure how to do that. any help will be great. Be easy on me

var vid = document.querySelector('#main');
        var topOfVid = vid.offsetTop;

```
    function fixVid() {
        if (window.scrollY >= topOfVid) {
            document.body.style.paddingTop = vid.offsetHeight + 'px';
            document.body.classList.add('fixed-vid');
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove('fixed-vid');
            document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', fixVid);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want, do you want to add the class when you scroll to the bottom of the video instead of the top?

Comment: sorry , i want to add both top and bottom . The aim is the video to be visible all the time.